# DropDownList datasource asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, formview

I have a problem with a DropDownList control connected to a datasource. I want to get the selected index shown when I edit the full formview, but every time I try to edit I get the first index of the table ... while the chosen index is different .. I tried to use the selectparameters, but it also doesn't work ! 
Here is my code.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="DDListDataSource" DataTextField="GradeGroupName" DataValueField="GradeGroupName" Height="18px" Width="164px" >
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DDListDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Dev201601ConnectionString %>"
     InsertCommand="INSERT INTO GradeGroups(GradeGroup) VALUES (@GradeGroup)"
     SelectCommand="SELECT GradeGroupName FROM GradeGroups"
     UpdateCommand="UPDATE GradeGroups SET GradeGroupName = @GradeGroup, GradeGroup = @GradeGroup WHERE (GradeGroup = @Original_GradeGroup)">
    <InsertParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="GradeGroup"></asp:Parameter>
    </InsertParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="GradeGroupName" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="GradeGroupName" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="GradeGroup" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="GradeGroup" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Original_GradeGroup" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: try to add AutoPostBack = "false" to your dropdownlist control

Comment: And I have one more question: why do you use InsertParameters twice?

Answer (score 2):

I like generating dropdownlist in a code-behind:

Design page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItems" runat="server" />
```

Code-behind in C#:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from table_name", con);

try
{
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds);
    ddlItems.DataSource = ds;
    ddlItems.DataTextField = "Name";
    ddlItems.DataValueField = "ID";
    ddlItems.DataBind();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //...
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Code-behind in VB.NET:

```
Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(conStr)
Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table_Name", con)

Try
   con.Open()
   Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
   Dim ds As New DataSet()
   sda.Fill(ds)
   ddlItems.DataSource = ds
   ddlItems.DataTextField = "Name"
   ddlItems.DataValueField = "ID"
   ddlItems.DataBind()
   con.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
   '....
End Try
```

Comment: I prefer this way, because you may manipulate with everything as you need

Comment: Well this is a better idea Thanks :)