# Emulate A DataBind to a DropdownList in VB.NET Using MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, binding, dropdownlistfor

I have an application where I need to populate a DropDownList using MySQL. This is easily done using

```
DropDownList1.Items.Add(“ItemName”)
```

The problem though is that I need to pass the database index for the `ItemName` rather than the default index.  I have tried to use

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(int index, “ItemName”)
```

for example,

```
   Using command As New MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, handle)
     Dim data_reader As MySqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
     While data_reader.Read
       Dim index = data_reader("Group ID")
       Dim item = data_reader("Group Name")
       DropDownList1.Items.Insert(index, item)
    End While
    data_reader.Close()
 End Using
```

but this fails due

```
"Insertion index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than or equal to size." & vbCrLf & "Parameter name: index"}
```

This is because I have no idea of what the index range will be.   Is there another way other than the programme capturing the indexes and mapping to the Database ID; which I really don't want to do.

Comment: Why not just bind the DropDownList to a DataSet, then use the DataTextField and DataValueField properties?  Maybe something like the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628589/dropdownlist-datasource-asp-net-vb

Comment: I can't do that because the DataSet is in Access and those controls appear to be bound to the  OLEDB version 4 connector which crashes, so I am trying to move to decouple myself from these bound interfaces,  and eventually to port to MySQL

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, if you're moving to MySql wouldn't it be the perfect time to re-wire the bindings and simplify things for yourself?

Comment: I have tried and tried - I have installed the .ACE.12.0 connector for all other database interfaces, but the controls that use binding remain glued to JET.OLEDB 4 - no matter what I do - short of hacking the registry

Comment: Yeah, you got me lost.  Your trying to do this with MySql are you not? What does OleDB, Ace 12 or Jet Odbc have to do with that?  If you're looking to migrate from Access to mysql, migrate and properly and not make your life more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Yes, I just realised my answer was not what you asked, but was the justification for moving to mySQL.   But that is what this question is about - how do I create those bindings?

Comment: Even so, there is zero reason you couldn't use databinding from a mysql sourced query for this combo, then yous what ever other mechanism you want to to connect to what ever other DB you have.  And check the link in 1st comment, shows exactly how to do it with vb.net or c#

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert something at an index that doesn't exist in a list, e.g. you can't insert at index 10 if a list only has 5 items. Actually data-binding is the logical option but, if you really must just insert items, the logical thing to do is to sort the items by the database ID first and then add them in that order. This obviously requires that those IDs be sequential at least. They should also start at zero, or else you'd have to add some offset to the index to get the actual ID.

Comment: Thankyou - that is a good idea, however I just realised that I can't guarantee that the first entry will be 0!

Comment: @Alexander, that's not necessarily a problem. As I said, as long as they are sequential, you're OK. You simply add the value of the first ID to the selected index to get the selected ID. If the first ID is 5 and the selected index is 0 then the selected ID is (0+5)=6 and if the selected index is 100 then the selected ID is (100+5)=105. Data-binding is still a better solution, but you should still understand this principle and it is actually the answer to the specific question you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Hursey 's comment, the answer lies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628589/dropdownlist-datasource-asp-net-vb) - but for context of this question here is my implementation based on that answer and hope it helps someone else.

```
Dim myData As New DataSet
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery 'Your query...
cmd.Connection = conn

myAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd
myAdapter.Fill(myData)
DropDownList1.DataSource() = myData
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Group ID"
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Group Name"
DropDownList1.DataBind()
```